# use Live reload when index file is in a folder

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, configuration, hybrid-mobile-app, livereload

I write an hybrid app, and my directory structure put index in a folder inside www, the directories seems like

```
cordova/wwww/SomeFolder/index.html
```

I write that in the cordova config.xml file:

```
<content src="SomeFolder/index.html"/>
```

when i made

```
ionic run android --device
```

all works, the app is intalled in a device and works fine.

the problem is when i try to use livereload:

```
ionic run -l android --device
```

the app is intalled in the device but not works, appears a message about not find the file index

in this stade I can open the app in the browser, say not wroks, but i can open the app if i add the folder name:

```
10.0.23.4:8100/SomeFolder/
```

the problem is when i save a modification in the browser appears the msg 404, i do change the adress to 10.0.23.4:8100/SomeFolder/ reload and navigate where i work, that is tedious.

Exist a way to configured livereload to search index in a folder and not in the root folder www?

Answer (score 0):

@Pablote: Have you tried the below

1. Add a new state in app.js under config state provider section.

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('some-folder', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/somefolder',
    templateUrl: "SomeFolder/index.html",
  })
});
```

2. Now you open browser with URL: http://localhost:8100/somefolder/ because we set the url as /some-folder. Modify your code and save, then see If live reload is working.

Comment: Not Works this solution, because SomeFolder/index.html is the first page so the system do go in there before charge angular

Comment: for that I use in Config.xml the line <content src="SomeFolder/index.html"/>    and works in the app but not in livereload